# csvreader and csvstyle with siunitx: "Paragraph ended before NC@rewrite@S was complete"

Tags: siunitx, csvsimple

I'm trying to define a csvstyle that I can use for multiple tables using csvreader, however I'm running into errors trying to separately format 'S' columns. Each table has the same column names and data types; they are simply results from differing experimental scenarios.

For the following data:

**Dataset1.csv**

```
Name,ValueA,ValueB,ValueC
John,623.95, 8.954847, 0.000772
Anna,602.40,8.93469, 0.000772
Jacob,1987.17,8.796296, 0.000926
```

This is the furthest I can get:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{filecontents*}{Dataset1.csv}
Name,ValueA,ValueB,ValueC
John,623.95, 8.954847, 0.000772
Anna,602.40,8.93469, 0.000772
Jacob,1987.17,8.796296, 0.000926
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\csvstyle{MyStyle}{
    head to column names,
    before reading=\centering\sisetup{table-number-alignment=center,table-format=4.4,table-auto-round},
    tabular=|c|S|S|S|,
    table head =\hline {Name} & {ValueA} & {ValueB} & {ValueC} \\\hline,
    table foot=\hline
}

\csvreader[MyStyle]{Dataset1.csv}{}{\Name & \ValueA & \ValueB & \ValueC}
\end{document}
%\csvreader[MyStyle]{Dataset2.csv}{}{\Name & \ValueA & \ValueB & \ValueC}
\end{document}
```

[image: Current Coding Results]

Any attempt to change an `S` into an `S[table-format=4.2]` (and remove it from `before reading`) so that I can column-by-column adjust the number of decimal places yields a

```
Paragraph ended before \\NC@rewrite@S was complete. ...sv}{}{\Name & \ValueA & \ValueB & \ValueC}
```

error. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can instead define the desired format as a new column type:

```
\newcolumntype{H}{S[table-format=4.2]}
```

Then you can use `H` instead of `S`, when desired and remove the format command from your `before reading` macro.

I have created an example of this on [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/fjtxqsqdsqbs).